# Clicking Outlook link in taskbar opens new window

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, taskbar

I have `Outlook` pinned to the `Windows 7` `Taskbar`. All the other apps I have pinned in the taskbar respond to clicking by focusing on the existing open window but Outlook opens a whole new window. Then, if I don't want to open a new Outlook window, I need to click the 2nd icon of Outlook in the taskbar, which corresponds to the active instance, and not the fixed taskbar icon, which is only a stub.

It didn't use to work like this, only after I removed Outlook from the `Start Menu`. How can I correct this behavior to not instantiate a new window when the default taskbar Outlook icon is clicked but to have a maximum of one Outlook window open, just as is the case with other taskbar items (unless I explicitly request a new window from that application)?

Comment: It was _always_ like that for me (and I hated it for five years at least). There is, however, a task bar setting that collapses the two entries into one, maybe you changed that, so you now _see_ the second window?

Comment: but none of the other apps from the taskbar act like that

Comment: the decision about what to do if a second process is started is in the application's code. Excel's (and others') code checks for existing running instances, and instead open those. Whoever coded Outlook did decide to open a second window would be good. It _could_ be there is a setting, but I don't know it.

Comment: Since about 1 month, I the same issue (win 10, outlook 365 sub). Before, clicking on outlook in the taskbar just brought outlook to the foreground. Now it creates a new instance, and eventually crashes outlook.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem but it proved to be a simple fix.

With Outlook not running, right click and unpin it from the task bar. Then click on Start and scroll to Outlook in the programs list. Right click on the Outlook icon and click on Pin to Taskbar.

Now the new icon opens without creating another window on the task bar. No idea why this has fixed it; just glad it has!

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution here: https://www.msoutlook.info/question/open-outlook-keyboard-shortcut . After you pinned Outlook to the taskbar

1. Right-click on the icon
2. Right-click on the "Outlook" item on the menu & select Properties
3. In the Target field, append " /recycle" to the end of the string
4. Outlook will now reuse existing window instead of opening a new one

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

right click the outlook icon in the task manager and unclick hide when minimized.   That was my problem too and now I only ever have one instance of out look running at one time

Answer (score 0):

You most probably pinned the shortcut of the file instead of the actual program. Find actual program, then right click it and select Pin to task bar.

Comment: How does that make a difference? The shortcut is only a pointer to the program.

Comment: no, that would not be the case.  i did the same as for any other application

Comment: I have the same issue and I have outlook pined, not a shortcut, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I simply removed the shortcut from the taskbar and then pinned the Outlook Desktop App from the Windows search/start.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by unpinning  the icon, then opening a new instance and pinning it again.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason: Running Windows 11 and you have configured the taskbar to show task icons only for the screen on which it is visible ("When using multiple displays, show my taskbar app on: Taskbar where window is open"). But you have pinned the Outlook icon to the main screen. Now when Outlook is moved to a secondary screen, clicking the pinned icon on the main screen launches a new window.

Haven't found a solution for this other than setting: "When using multiple displays, show my taskbar app on: Main taskbar and taskbar where window is open"